# Using hot corners, spread all windows function, all preview images are blank... any ideas?

Tags: unity, 13.10

Using Ubuntu 13.10 and unity tweak tool. I have the hot corners feature setup to spread all windows when I go to the bottom left corner. However ~97.63% of the time when I spread all windows, all previews are blank, and when I hover the mouse over them, I can see the highlighted boarder of the window/application, but the screen is blank otherwise. If I click the empty window preview the correct window will open, and then when I go back to spread all windows, and the one I clicked is visible and the rest are still blank. I then have to go through and click all the empty previews one at a time to find the one I'm looking for. This is almost unusable. Has anyone had this problem or does anyone know some possible solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bug in Compiz or the Compiz Plugin. You should file a bug report instead.

Answer (score 0):

just started with linux. And loving every single bit of it. I did not have this problem when i first installed it worked perfect for me at start. But then i started tweaking on some small things to fit my personal use better. When i did this i got the same issue/problems like you do.

What seems to do the blank previews for me was when i checked the box "Click to access desktop". I really loved this option but it seems to make the preview disappear for me.

1. Open unity tweak tool
2. Click window spread
3. Uncheck "Click to access desktop" option. Simply use the default settings.

Hope this helps for you as it did me. Good luck mate